# How to precompute costly code fragment in advance in React?

Tags: reactjs, optimization, webpack, compilation

We have a React component that uses data provided by some long computation. The provided data (result of a long computation) is always the same (for all users).

What i want to do is to ensure that this computation is executed once (during minification), instead of every time user loads the page.

Webpack uses [TerserPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/) for minification by default, when in production mode.

- Is TerserPlugin clever enough to figure out that the long computation always returns the same result and optimise it?
- If so, is there a way to check that the computation does not execute at runtime? `console.log` would definitely prevent the optimisation.
- If not, maybe another plugins can do that? For example UglifyJS.

Simplified webpack configuration:

```
...

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',

  entry: {
    app: ['...'],
  },
  output: {
    path: '...',
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jsx?|tsx?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        }
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [.ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, "./src"),
    ]
  },
};
```

The only way i can imagine is to create a script that creates a json file with desired data

- Is this a good solution or is there a better, simpler one? Some downsides are for example: linter may complain that imports don't exist, more complicated setup.

Here is a [**demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-how-to-precompute-costly-code-fragment-in-advance-in-react-rrntr) with example use case.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is the same within all the users, you should cache the data on the backend if a backend is present.

If the data is unique the each client but you want the client to do less computing, look at react.memo.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The data is always the same for all users. Im looking for a solution that allows to optimise data in a way that is not reconstructed from scratch by long computation when user loads the page.

Comment: The source of data is from a file local to frontend ? Or in a database and you fetch it on the frontend ?

Comment: The source of data is a script, in the frontend (as in the demo)

Comment: Oh good, you can simply add the script in the frontend dir and called it directly in the package.json on build/start command as you wish.